# AEM cq dialog with datetime as xtype saves unparseable date "Y-4-21\P20:i:0.000P"

Tags: datepicker, dialog, aem, datetime-format

As part of scheduled process we need to accept user input date time with timezone in a cq dialog for a workflow
to later read and wait until using absolute time handler and execute a process.

But some time we get unparseable date
"Y- 4-21\P20:i:0.000P" error 
as we are expecting a date in 
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:MM:ss.SSS Z"

and we do get a date as below sometime
 "2017-04-21T20:05:00.000+05:30"

The error doesn't happen all the time, we are using cq dialog with xtype datetime

In widgets api CQ.form.DateTime we find

hiddenFormat : String
Format of datetime used to store value in hidden field and submitted to server (defaults to 'Y-m-d\TH:i:sP' ).

Tried few format as value to dateFormat : String
Format of DateField. (defaults to CQ.Ext.form.DateField.prototype.format)

Please suggest what can be done to handle this in a better way.
Or how can we store date using cq dialog in efficient way to handle timezones and which format.

Comment: @i.net Did you find this weird behavior of xtype datetime dialog

Comment: I've had lots of (& similar) issues with xtype datetime especially acoss browsers and timezones and OS so I resorted to good old milliseconds date while separating user's time zone in their preferences (or separate input field which defaults to their timezone).